# Mean function given a list of graphs

Tags: python, graphics

I need a function that, given a list of graphs, builds a new
graph in which for each abscissa the ordinate is the average of the ordinate of the several graphs supplied.

The data for each graph is a pair of lists of numbers, the first of which is the abscissa and the ordinate the second.

The function should assume that all graphs have the same abscissa lists.

For example:

```
abscissa = range(1, 4)
graphs = [
    (abscissa, [1, 2, 3]),
    (abscissa, [4, 5, 6]),
    (abscissa, [7, 8, 9])
]

function(graphs)
```

Expected return from `function(graphs)`:

```
([1, 2, 3], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0])
```

Comment: What is "a list of graphics"?

Comment: pair of lists of numbers , the first of which is the abscissa and
the second ordered

Comment: Please give proper information and post complete questions

Comment: @Lusokid: please edit your question providing a more precise definition of the expected input and a sample so that we can better help you. Thank you.

Comment: @Lusokid: Put a small example of this input data (formatted in a code block) into your question. Even better: also add some code that attempts to do what you want, and we'll help you fix it. But show us the data first!

Comment: did it already,sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `zip` function to easily add the corresponding ordinates from each ordinate list, by using the "splat" operator `*`. This tells `zip` to treat each list in `ylists` as an argument, so it zips all of those lists together, creating a list of tuples. The first tuple in the resulting list contains all the 1st members of each list in `ylist`, the 2nd tuple in the resulting list contains all the 2nd members of each list in `ylist`, etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Find means of graph data '''

def mean_graph(graphs):
    abscissa = graphs[0][0]

    #Extract ordinate lists
    ylists = [g[1] for g in graphs]

    #Find means of corresponding ordinates
    size = float(len(graphs))
    means = [sum(v) / size for v in zip(*ylists)]

    return abscissa, means


abscissa = range(1, 4)
graphs = [
    (abscissa, [1, 2, 3]),
    (abscissa, [4, 5, 6]),
    (abscissa, [7, 8, 9]),
]

print(mean_graph(graphs))
```

**output**

```
([1, 2, 3], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0])
```

I developed the above code on Python 2.6.6. On Python 3 you can change
`size = float(len(graphs))`
to
`size = len(graphs)`

---

FWIW, it's possible to condense the `mean_graph` function into one line, although it does make it a little harder to read:

```
def mean_graph(graphs):
    return graphs[0][0], [sum(v) / float(len(graphs)) for v in zip(*[g[1] for g in graphs])]
```

or for Python 3:

```
def mean_graph(graphs):
    return graphs[0][0], [sum(v) / len(graphs) for v in zip(*[g[1] for g in graphs])]
```

Comment: can you explain me what you did after the first return?

Comment: @Lusokid: `return abscissa, means` creates a tuple of the `abscissa` and  `means` lists, and returns that tuple. So you _could_ write it as `return (abscissa, means)`, but it looks cleaner to leave the `(` and `)` out. See the example of tuple packing in [Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) in the official Python Tutorial.